# Confused by Django's ImageField width and height

Tags: django, image

I have added the image `width` and `height` fields to an ImageField-based model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    height = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=settings.PHOTO_UPLOAD_TO,
        height_field='height',
        width_field='width'
    )
```

When I do `manage.py makemigrations`, I am asked for the default value for existing rows. I already have many photos in the database (it's a running site), therefore I chose to add `default=0` to `width` and `height`.

```
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now for all existing photos the two columns are populated with zeros, as expected. What I didn't expect however was that `Photo.objects.all()[0].width` and `.height` now return the correct non-zero values. Why? I couldn't find anything about such behaviour in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just went through the exact same situation you did. Turns out EVERY existing image now has the correct `width` and `height` values.

Comment: @Nifled, no, I didn't.

Comment: @Nifled, now there is an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the magic is being performed in Django's `ImageField.update_dimension_fields` method. The comments in the code say:

> Update field's width and height fields, if defined.
>
> This method is hooked up to model's post_init signal to update
>           dimensions after instantiating a model instance.  However, dimensions
>           won't be updated if the dimensions fields are already populated.  This
>           avoids unnecessary recalculation when loading an object from the
>           database.
>
> Dimensions can be forced to update with `force=True`, which is how
>           `ImageFileDescriptor.__set__` calls this method.

So when instantiating the model, `update_dimension_fields` reads the dimensions from the image file and stores those on the instance. This will incur a little hit in a live environment.

Saving all images will store the dimensions in the database:

```
In [1]: for p in Photo.objects.all():
   ...:     p.save()
```

Comment: Looks like this is the correct answer, but I'll check it before accepting. Thanks, +1.

Comment: @texnic And... did you check?

Comment: yes, looks like you're right :) It also helped me localize and resolve a time waster in my project, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField.height_field

> **ImageField.height_field:**
>
> Name of a model field which will be
> **auto-populated** with the height of the image **each time the model
> instance is saved**.

model save() must have auto-populated both the `height` and `width`

Comment: But I haven't saved anything, that's the point. The images are already in the database. And the height and width columns are both zero in DB. I am retrieving data, not saving it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: during migrations, setting the default to 0 might trigger a save right !

Comment: I may be wrong, but I actually doubt it. Migration changes the database scheme but it doesn't, to the best of my knowledge, trigger saving on existing rows. That's exactly why I have zero width and height for existing photos.